# laravel can not access to relation attributes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have model product as follow:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    //

    public function Category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
    public function size_unit(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\size_unit', 'size_unit');
    }
}
```

the size_units table have two columns: id, unit
the product table have size_unit column which is foreign key that reference the id on size_units table

when I try to access unit column for product using:

```
{{ $product->size_unit->unit }}
```

I get the following error:

> "Trying to get property 'unit' of non-object"

but when I use:

```
{{ dd($product->size_unit() }}
```

I can see the unit under relation -> attributes, so I tried to use:

```
$product->size_unit()->unit
```

I get the following error:

> "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$unit"

i am fetching the product using with('size_unit)

please tell me what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: You can try to use camel case for naming, e.g. `sizeUnit` and `SizeUnit` for the class and make sure you have your foreign keys correct.

Answer (score 0):

Rename `size_unit` class to `SizeUnit` and your relationship should be like below.

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}

public function sizeUnit(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\SizeUnit', 'size_unit');
}
```

You should access sizeUnit properties like this:

```
dd($product->sizeUnit);
```

[Follow Laravel naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions)